# AngularJS getting data from service

Tags: angularjs, http, service, controller, promise

I have a service method for getting some data. The service method will first check the local storage for the presence of that data, if present then it will return else it will fetch the data from server using $resource and return  after storing it in local storage. From my controller I will call this service to get the data. My question is, how to make sure that data is returned after the ajax call is over. when I call the below service from my controller the first time I get `undefined`

```
services.factory('dataService', ['country','localStorageService',function(country,localStorageService) {
 return { 

    getCountryList: function (){
                     var countryList = null;
                     if(localStorageService.isSupported) {
                            countryList = localStorageService.get("countryList");
                     }
                     if(countryList !==null){
                        return countryList ;
                     }
                     else{
                        country.query(function(response) {
                            countryList = response;
                            if(localStorageService.isSupported) {
                                localStorageService.set("countryList ",countryList );
                            }
                            return countryList ;
                        });
                     }



                 }
    }
}]);


services.factory('country',['$resource','serverConfig',function($resource,serverConfig) {
     return $resource(serverConfig.url+'/country');
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The $http service may be of use to you here.

It makes use of promise functions which are called based on whether the response was received or whether an error occured attempting to gather the resource.

```
$http.post("link.php").
    then(function(response) {
        // called when successful
    }, function(response) {
        // called when not successful
    });
```

Anything printed (echo, print_r, var_dump) by the `link.php` will be returned as response as the function parameter.

Bare in mind that you will have to pass the $http service into the controller.

```
.controller("ItemController", function($scope, $http) {
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: I updated my question with the code, can you tell what is wrong with it

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with your service. However it doesn't look all that readable to me. Why not try with the method I posted? It's the recommended way to gather data via HTTP requests.

Also - what data is it you're trying to gather?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it using $q service.

```
services.factory('dataService', ['$q','country','localStorageService',function($q,country,localStorageService) {

 return { 

    getCountryList: function(){
                     var deferred = $q.defer();
                     var countryList = null;
                     if(localStorageService.isSupported) {
                            countryList = localStorageService.get("countryList");
                     }
                     if(countryList !==null){
                        deferred.resolve(countryList);
                     }
                     else{
                        country.query(function(response) {
                            countryList = response;
                            if(localStorageService.isSupported) {
                                localStorageService.set("countryList ",countryList);
                            }
                            deferred.resolve(countryList);
                        });
                     }

                     return deferred.promise;

            }
    }
}]);
```